# How can we trace a TCP/IP packet in a server

Tags: networking, tcp, ipc

I'm developing a backend service. The backend contains some processes, meaning that when a client sends a request to my server, the request will go through these processes.

For example, a request will be sent first to the `nginx` process, then be sent to the `http_proxy` process, and then to sent to the `request_handler` process.

What I need to do is to trace the route of a request as below:

```
req             ---> nginx:8888
nginx:4444      ---> http_proxy:7777
http_proxy:2222 ---> request_handler:6666
```

It means that the `req` is sent to the process `nginx` through the port `8888`, and `nginx` sends another packet from the port `4444` to the port `7777` so that the packet is received by the proceess `http_proxy`, then, `http_proxy` sent another packet from the port `2222` to the port `6666` so that the packet is received by the process `request_handler`.

It doesn't seem that `netstat` and `lsof` could do what I need. Is there some method or some tool to do so?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say this, but what you either need is better understanding of TCP/IP, or you don't need TCP/IP at all.

Application logging is probably the answer to your problem, but it depends on your applications.

You write "`nginx` sends another packet from the port `4444` to the port `7777`". I'm quite sure that it does not send from a fixed port. Doing that would limit the "concurrent" requests to one. Also, a request is not one packet but many, looking at the network details is usually not useful to deal with problems at the application level.

If you want to look at TCP/IP packets, the tool is `tcpdump`, not `netstat` or `lsof`.

Comment: Well, I know what you mentioned here. A request may be sent separately, yes. The port that used to send is not fixed, yes. But I just want to know the whole route, that's why I post this question.

Comment: Or, we can ignore the sending ports, that's OK. If we can figure out `req --> nginx:8888 --> http_proxy:7777 --> request_handler:6666`, that would be very helpful too.

Comment: You can use `tcpdump`, but you won't like the result, especially if the data is encrypted.

Comment: Yea... That's why I'm asking if we have some simple way or tool to do so